# Beginner to Unity Hub Error Failed to resolve project template:

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Hello I'm a total beginner to Unity and just installed. Every time I try to create new 3D project, Error window pop up "Failed to resolve project template: [com.unity.template.3d] is not a valid project template." any suggestions on what to do? Unity 3.3.0

I tried googling the answer but it seems that the Error for everyone else is different than mine.

Comment: Make sure the directory path where you are creating the new project has no spaces or non-alphanumeric characters in it.

Comment: Unity 3? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

Try completely uninstalling unity hub and any installs of unity then reinstalling it. Also, check that you have the appropriate C# sdks installed (use Visual Studio installer on Windows, Visual Studio for Mac on Mac).

Answer (score 0):

As Isaac said, try uninstall Unity and reinstall, you could also consideer installing an other version of Unity, even if this one isn't known for building problems, I Had same issue earlier the version of Unity just didn't work on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure the Unity (editor) has been installed properly. You can also try installing previous versions of the editor from the "Installs" tab. In my case, my Unity was corrupted while downloading and above solution seemed to work pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

i just found the fix, go to "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\ProjectTemplates" in your file manager, and delete all zip files that include the phrase "3d" or whatever the error says, in my case it was "com.unity.template.3dextra(insert version num here).zip". continue to shut down unity hub for good measure, and when you start it up again you can redownload the core 3d template, fixing the issue and updating your core 3d file!!!! i was very relieved when i fixed it, so i decided to help ya out :3